# Django app where the data is from external web services instead of database

Tags: django, web-services, django-models

I am planning to develop a Django app where most of the data is in external web services, rather than stored in the database that Django will use. How do I construct models in this case? Can I use plain strings and ints instead of Django field types, or prevent Django from writing fields to the database?

Comment: What features of Django models do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct your models as normal... just avoid calling `save()` on your model instances.

However you get very little benefit from using Django models at all, since they are part of the ORM and the functionality is mostly related to databases.

If the web service is over json then you might as well just use the dict/list objects you get from `simplejson.loads`

If the web service is SOAP try http://soapy.sourceforge.net/

If you need validation of the service responses you could consider making Django forms and passing the parsed dicts as `data` in place of `request.POST` like you'd normally do.

Comment: Thanks. It does turn out that I don't need to use Django models at all; I had just never seen Django without models before.